# Jackson de/serialization by Key trouble

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to de/serialize an `Entity` to its `EntityDTO`. The trouble is that `Entity` class has a `collection<KeyValue>` where:

```
class KeyValueDTO {
   private String key;
   private Object value;
}
```

and `Entity` has a collection of `KeyValue`:

```
class KeyValue {
   private String key;
   private Object[] values;
}
```

So, the way how data is stored in each case is slightly different. So,

```
KeyValueDTO dto1 = new KeyValueDTO("k1", "v1");
KeyValueDTO dto2 = new KeyValueDTO("k1", "v2");
KeyValueDTO dto3 = new KeyValueDTO("k1", "v3");
```

and using `KeyValue` class:

```
KeyValue values = new KeyValue("k1", new Object[] { "v1", "v2", "v3"});
```

Then, `Entity` class is

```
class Entity {
    List<KeyValue> values;
}
```

and,

```
class EntityDTO {
    List<KeyValueDTO> values;
}
```

I need to map a json like:

```
[ {"k1": "v1"}, {"k1": "v2"}, {"k1": "v3"} ]
```

to a `List<KeyValue>`. So, `values` property has to have one element `KeyValue::key => "k1"` and `KeyValue::values => {"v1", "v2", "v3"}`.

I'm using jackson in order to de/serialize each REST method parameter. So, I need to map from `Entity` to `EntityDTO` and from `EntityDTO` to `Entity`.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is invalid JSON. Please clarify.

Comment: The only way of doing this IMO is to put this your List<KeyValueDTO> and once transformed into an object, you iterate over your List to put this in a map. But it is ugly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson won't handle transformations like that, so you need to do the transformations yourself.

You're asking for two transformations:

1. Entity -> EntityDTO
2. EntityDTO -> Entity

These are not trival transformation but they're not too bad either. Java 8 with the new Streams API is perfect for these types of transformations.

Here you go:

```
    Entity entityToTransform = new Entity();
    EntityDTO entityDtoToTransform = new EntityDTO();

    // Entity -> EntityDTO
    // transform the list of KeyValues to KeyValueDTOs
    List<KeyValueDTO> keyValueDtos = entityToTransform.getValues().stream(
    ).flatMap(
        keyValue -> Arrays.stream(
            keyValue.getValues()
        ).map(
            value -> new KeyValueDTO(keyValue.getKey(), value)
        )
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // set the object
    EntityDTO entityDto = new EntityDTO(keyValueDtos);


    // EntityDTO -> Entity
    // transforms the list of KeyValueDTOs to KeyValues
    List<KeyValue> keyValues = entityDtoToTransform.getValues().stream(
    ).collect(
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(keyValueDto -> keyValueDto.getKey()),
            groupings -> groupings.entrySet().stream(
            ).map(
                entry -> new KeyValue(
                    entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue().stream(
                    ).map(
                        keyValueDto -> keyValueDto.getValue()
                    ).collect(
                        Collectors.toList()
                    ).toArray(
                        new Object[entry.getValue().size()]
                    )
                )
            ).collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    );

    Entity entity = new Entity(keyValues);
```